# send variable from browser to dash plotly dashboard

Tags: flask, plotly, plotly-dash

I am using "value" as a static variable in code. When I run this I get "http://127.0.0.1:8050/" where I can see my dash application. I need "value" as a dynamic variable which I can pass in browser.
E.g. if I type http://127.0.0.1:8050/198 in browser it should display 198 instead of 270.

Thank you so much for your help :)

Sharing Code and output result as image

```
import flask
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import dash_core_components as dcc

server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server)

fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
    mode = "gauge+number",
    value = 270,
    domain = {'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
    title = {'text': "Speed"}))

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Graph(
        id='life-exp-vs-gdp',
        figure=fig
    )
])
@server.route('/test', methods=['POST'])
def req():
    print('Request triggered!')  # For debugging purposes, prints to console
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Update the figure using @app.callback

1. from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
2. input to the callback is url - pathname, and for url, you need to add dcc.Location() in your layout - make sure the id matches with callback input. The pathname received by the callback would contain "/". It is basically the path after your host:ip. Remove the "/" and convert the pathname to int() and then assign this value to the graph "value" in the go.Figure()
3. Output is the figure after updating the graph. Make sure the graph id in layout matches the callback output id.

Your code looks like this:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import flask
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

server = flask.Flask(__name__)
app = dash.Dash(__name__, server=server)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Location(id='url', refresh=False),
    dcc.Graph(
        id='life-exp-vs-gdp'
    )
])


@app.callback(Output('life-exp-vs-gdp', 'figure'), Input('url', 'pathname'))
def display_page(pathname):
    if pathname == "/":
        pathname = 200
    else:
        pathname = int(pathname.strip('/'))

    fig = go.Figure(go.Indicator(
        mode="gauge+number",
        value=pathname,
        domain={'x': [0, 1], 'y': [0, 1]},
        title={'text': "Speed"}))
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

So, if you open: http://127.0.0.1:8050/, this will have some default value in the gauge. And if you open: http://127.0.0.1:8050/198, this will have 198 value in the gauge.

I hope, this is useful.